# Get Array Ajax Response Undefined

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to send an array to JS, but I can't get the array I want.

This is my Controller PHP code:

```
foreach ($test as $k => $subArray) {
   foreach ($subArray as $id=>$value) {
      array_key_exists( $id, $sumArray ) ? $sumArray[$id] += $value : $sumArray[$id] = $value;
   }
}
array_push($t, $sumArray);
$data['res'] = array_values($t[0]);
array_push($temp, $data);
echo json_encode($temp);
```

The output was:

```
[{"res":[484603732,350203732,133347732,203347732]}]
```

This is my View code:

```
$.get('/index.php/dashboard/linechart', function(data){
     console.log(data.res);
});
```

My expected output on console.log was:

```
[484603732,350203732,133347732,203347732]
```

but something goes wrong, the output went `undefined.`

So far I've tried with `JSON.parse(data.res);`

But still got undefined.

Anyone could save my day? I'm really stuck with this.

Comment: You've to parse `data` to an object, your server sends a JSON string. Notice also, that `res` is a member of the array, hence `data[0].res` is what you need.

Comment: Could you please show me how to do it? Coz I've tried all of the methods I know. But still, it goes error.

Comment: This should not be extremely hard, take some time, examine carefully what you have written and what kind of results you're having, and re-read my comment, practically the code you need is in that comment.

Comment: Hi Can you use something like this instead of JSON.parse ?

JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data.res));

Comment: @HariharanV. Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0

Comment: What about 

response = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));

alert(response);

for(var i in response){
    alert(response[i].res);
}

Comment: `let parsedData = JSON.parse(data); let res = parsedData[0].res;` should do. Server always responses with a string, live objects are not going through the http(s).

Comment: When you receive a response from the server, the data is on string format, what you can do is either parse the `res` and access the data ( the reason behind undefined is there is no array in `key => value` format currently ) or send an array from the server without encoding.

Comment: could you log just data and show us the output in javascript

Answer (score 1):

As per your output:

```
[{"res":[484603732,350203732,133347732,203347732]}]
```

The issue is with the response. You're returning an array and not an object.
So your ajax should be doing something like this:

```
$.get('/index.php/dashboard/linechart', function(data){
 actualData = JSON.parse(data); 
 console.log(actualData[0].res);
});
```

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

Comment: Hi, can you just log ```data``` and show the output.

Comment: If I'm trying to console.log(data), the output was empty.